# Reducing MySQL Query Time (Currently running for 24 hours and still going)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a database with three tables and I need to cross reference the first table against the other two to create a fourth table of consolidated information. All the tables have one field which is common, this is the MSISDN (mobile / cell telephone number) and is at least 10 digits long.

Table 1 - 819,248 rows

Table 2 - 75,308,813 rows

Table 3 - 17,701,196 rows

I want to return all the rows from Table 1 and append some of the fields from Tables 2 and Table 3 when there's a matching MSISDN.
My query has been running now for over 24 hours and I have no way of knowing how long something like this should take.

This type of query may be a regular project - is there a way to significantly reduce the query time?

I have indexed tables 2 and 3 with MSISDN and the fields I need to return.

My query is like this:

```
create TABLE FinishedData 
select 
   Table1.ADDRESS, table1.POSTAL, table1.MOBILE, 
   table1.FIRST, table1.LAST, table1.MID, table1.CARRIER, 
   table1.TOWN, table1.ID, table2.status as 'status1', 
   table2.CurrentNetworkName as 'currentnetwork1', 
   table2.DateChecked as 'datechecked1', table3.Status as 'status2', 
   table3.CurrentNetworkName 'currentnetwork2', 
   table3.DateChecked as 'datechecked2' 
from 
   table1 left join (table2, table3) 
       on (right(table1.MOBILE, 10) = right(table2.MSISDN, 10) 
       AND right(table1.MOBILE,10) = right(table3.MSISDN,10))
```

MySQL is running on a 64bit windows machine with 12GB memory and 8 logical cores @ 3GHz. MySQLd is only using 10% cpu and 600MB of resources when running the query.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **kill performance issue is with right function** When you use this function, MySQL can't use indexes.

My suggest is:

1. Create new fields in table2 and table 3 with [reverse](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) content of MSISDN
2. Make the join replacing right function by left function.

With this little change MySQL will can take indexes to make your joins.

**Explained steps:**

1) Create new columns:

```
Alter table table2 add column r_MSISDN varchar(200);
update table2 set r_MSISDN = reverse( MSISDN );

Alter table table3 add column r_MSISDN varchar(200);
update table3 set r_MSISDN = reverse( MSISDN );
```

2) New join:

```
...
from 
   table1 left join (table2, table3) 
       on (right(table1.MOBILE, 10) = left(table2.r_MSISDN, 10) 
       AND right(table1.MOBILE,10) = left(table3.r_MSISDN,10))
```

Comment: Thanks danihp - it certainly seems to be the 'right' function that is causing the problem. I guess from your post that 'left' does not have the same problem. I will try creating new columns with normalized data and then avoid using 'right' or 'left' - this avoids me having to reverse data again in the future if I add more. I am using your code to create the new columns but instead of reversing the data I am normalising it.

Answer (score 1):

[`RIGHT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) is a function. Using a function in where clause means MySQL (and perhaps any database) cannot use an index because it has to compute the value returned by the function for each row before comparing.

If you want to make this query any faster, consider storing the MSISDN in a normalized form and comparing using `=` operator.

Now I am not sure what MSISDN number looks like. If it is a fixed width number then your job is easy. If it contains separators (spaces/hyphens) and the separators are only there for readability you should remove them before storing in database. If the first 10 characters are important and remaining are optional, you might consider storing the first 10 and remaining characters in separate columns.

Comment: Thank you Salman. I am creating new columns using the code suggested by danihp but normalising the data instead of reversing it. I think I should have originally done this anyway so this nis the solution I will use. This also means in the future I can normalise more MSISDNs and query against these.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, the problem is with the `right` function which does not allow using any indexes.

In simple words, your current query for each row in table1 makes a full scan of table2 and for each match makes a full scan of table3. Considering how many rows you have in table2 and table3, you have a good chance to see the world before the query is finished.

Another problem is that the query initiates a huge transaction which should be able, as MySQL thinks, to be rolled back and you might think over the isolation level.

I would not change the current tables though. I would create subcopies of table2 and table3 with the required columns, and add the right(table2.MSISDN, 10) as a separate indexed column in table2 copy (right(table3.MSISDN,10) in table3 copy).

Then, you can do the LEFT JOIN with the copies, or even reduce the copies to the rows which do match anything in table1 and do the LEFT JOIN then.

Comment: Thank you for the help newtover. I started creating the new columns before you had posted so I will finish this and check that it works. As I may be referencing table2 and table3 again in the future I may want different columns so I will try and avoid creating new tables each time. I don't have enough rep to vote up your response - sorry! I need 15 rep or more.